# Django: request from RequestFactory on Windows does not include session attribute

Tags: python, django

My drone pipeline suddenly started failing on Windows only (the Linux pipeline, executing the same tests, works fine).

error:

> ```
> assert hasattr(request, 'session'), "The session-based temporary "\ AssertionError: The session-based temporary message storage
> ```
>
> requires session middleware to be installed, and come before the
> message middleware in the MIDDLEWARE list

Looking at RequestFactory, this does indeed not give a session, but somehow it works on Linux and it used to work on Windows too. What has changed, why? And how should I add a dummy session to the request?

**test.py**

```
class TestDynamicAlertSubscriptionAdminModule(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        request = RequestFactory().post(path="dummy")
        request.user = self.user
        request._messages = messages.storage.default_storage(request)
```

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
]
```

Comment: I am guessing two possibilities: 1) Your two pipelines are running different versions of your code. 2) The pipelines have different values for the [MESSAGE_STORAGE setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#message-storage)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks for pointing me in the right direction. There was indeed a different value for the MESSAGE_STORAGE setting which I had added to the linux version of the settings file for the purpose of testing. I would have thought this to have a sensible default if not specified, but apparently this wasn't the case. If you want to write this as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why is the session attribute not present on the request?

You're using `RequestFactory` to create your request and directly passing it to the view, this means the request doesn't go through any of the middleware and since `SessionMiddleware` is responsible for setting up the session it doesn't work. This is described more in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39947296/django-testing-access-session-in-requestfactory).

### Why does this work on one environment and not the other?

The messages can be stored in different backends depending on the [`MESSAGE_STORAGE` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#message-storage). Given you have two different environments there's a possibility that this setting is configured differently for the environments where one is using the `SessionStorage` and another is using one of `FallbackStorage` or `CookieStorage`. The environment using `SessionStorage` will fail and error out while the other will succeed since they don't rely on the session.